# 'The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am working with EF6 and MVC 4. My aim is to be able to transfer the data from the class library using EF6 to the project using .net core

DataLayer Project **-Using Template(Class Library(.Net Framework))**

```
public static List<ItemEx> GetItems()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var context = new itemExDBEntities())
                {
                    return context.ItemExes.ToList();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

WebAPI Project **-Using Template(Asp.Net Web API(.Net Core 3.1))**

```
        [HttpGet("GetList")]
        public string GetList()
        {
            return JsonHelper.ToJsonString(DataClass.GetItems());
        }
```

I cannot transfer data from the data layer. This error appears.
What do you think could be the problem?

```
System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.'
```